# View count not real

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

[**My Question**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1983/are-the-events-in-black-gold-based-on-fact) Question shows 1 view but I know it's not real because someone edited the Q so he must have seen it. It should have least 2 views. I noticed this happens on all SE sites with many questions so what's up?[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Caching. The answer on things like this is always caching. Give it an hour.

Also, the view counter on Stack Exchange is *extremely* conservative. Actual views will nearly always be somewhat higher than the number displayed.